# Set date format Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I want to convert this string "Sat, 01 Aug 2015 21:03:59 GMT" to NSDate object

Here's my code

```
+(NSDate *)getDateFromDateString :(NSString *)dateString {
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
return date;}
```

but date always is nil. I guess something wrong with date format. Can someone please give me some advice?

Comment: the code is correct. How do you call this method?

Comment: Are you certain the NSString you are passing to the method is valid? Not nil?

Comment: yep, i'm sure that my string is valid

Comment: I try to call this method with a valid string, but date always nil.   NSDate *time = [NSDate getDateFromDateString:@"Sat, 01 Aug 2015 21:03:59 GMT" ];

Comment: the code works declared in a category of NSDate

Comment: @vadian yep, i 've already declared the code in a category of NSDate

Comment: You need EEE for the abbreviated weekday.

Comment: The code is correct just like vadian said. Have you checked if the date variable within the function is nil or you just assume it is nil after passing it to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your support, i found out the answer. Need to declare the locale

`[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];`

Comment: Yes without that you can get the correct result from simulator but not necessarily the real device.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is how I would call a utility function:

***DateHelperClass.h***

```
+ (NSDate *)getDateFromDateString :(NSString *)dateString;
```

***DateHelperClass.m***

```
+ (NSDate *)getDateFromDateString :(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    return date;
}
```

***SomeOtherClass.m***

```
#import "DateHelperClass.h"

- (void)convertDate
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[DateHelperClass getDateFromDateString:@"Sat, 01 Aug 2015 21:03:59 GMT"]);
}
```

**Result**:

> 2015-08-01 21:03:59 +0000